# SailsJS, Waterline populate records with select

Tags: orm, sails.js, waterline

I have looked at a lot of old SO questions which have broken GitHub links and SailsJS Trello, however I am still unclear.

Is it possible, to populate a field (one-to-one relationship) in SailsJS and return only specific fields (either via select or omit).

```
await Document.find({id: id}).populate('createdBy', {select: ['name']})
```

I am getting

```
UsageError: Invalid populate(s).
Details:
  Could not populate `createdBy` because of ambiguous usage.  This is a singular ("model") association, which means it never refers to more than _one_ associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association
, since it generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's the trouble-- it looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) _was_ provided!
(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special case that _does_ make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version of Waterline.)

Here's what was passed in:
{ select: [ 'name' ] }
```

In models,

```
createdBy: {
      model: 'user',
      description: 'Who is this document assigned to'
    },
```

I am using sails `1.1.0`, waterline `0.13.5-0`

Am I doing this right? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem and made a pull request. Since the pull request has not yet been accepted, be careful and use it on your ask.

Go to

> node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/forge-stage-two-query.js

Go to this section

```js
// If this is a singular ("model") association, then it should always have
// an empty dictionary on the RHS.  (For this type of association, there is
// always either exactly one associated record, or none of them.)
if (populateAttrDef.model) {....}
```

Change it to:

```js
     if (populateAttrDef.model) {

        // Tolerate a subcriteria of `{}`, interpreting it to mean that there is
        // really no criteria at all, and that we should just use `true` (the
        // default "enabled" value for singular "model" associations.)
        if (_.isEqual(query.populates[populateAttrName], {})) {
          query.populates[populateAttrName] = true;
        }
        // Otherwise, this simply must be `true`.  Otherwise it's invalid.
        else {

          if (query.populates[populateAttrName] !== true && (_.isUndefined(query.populates[populateAttrName].select) && _.isUndefined(query.populates[populateAttrName].omit))) {
            throw buildUsageError(
              'E_INVALID_POPULATES',
              'Could not populate `'+populateAttrName+'` because of ambiguous usage.  '+
              'This is a singular ("model") association, which means it never refers to '+
              'more than _one_ associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as '+
              'the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, '+
              'since it generally wouldn\'t make any sense.  But that\'s the trouble-- it '+
              'looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) _was_ provided!\n'+
              '(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special '+
              'case that _does_ make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version '+
              'of Waterline.)\n'+
              '\n'+
              'Here\'s what was passed in:\n'+
              util.inspect(query.populates[populateAttrName], {depth: 5}),
              query.using
            );
          }//-•
          else {
            query.populates[populateAttrName] = {
              select: query.populates[populateAttrName].select? query.populates[populateAttrName].select : undefined,
              omit: query.populates[populateAttrName].omit? query.populates[populateAttrName].omit : undefined
            };
          }

        }//>-•

      }
```

**This is the pull request to see exactly what you should change:**
**https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/1613**

Answer (score 1):

When u use One-to-one association u can't use subcriteria like error say.

```
So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association
```

U can use `customToJSON` function on model `createdBy` to omit data.

```
customToJSON: function() {

  return _.omit(this, ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'id'])
}
```

Comment: Will cutomToJson function fire when using a find() function? I have added it to Document and User models, however it doesn't get triggered at all. In fact even User.findOne({id: id}) returns the full record, including the omitted fields.

Comment: Did you set up the function well?
`{
attributes: {},
customToJSON: function () {
   return _.omit (this, ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'id'])
}
}`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it's set up (with `attributes` containing the fields). I have been trying to debugg it but no luck

Comment: With a customToJSON method the whole record will be returned from the database, but when returning some JSON response from a controller (ie `exits.success({ records: theReturnedRecords })` it should run before sending out the HTTP response. This is semi-useful for things like not accidentally handing out user passwords, but here probably not so much.
As the warning generated by Sails/Waterline says about your initial usage with `select`: "This usage will be supported in a future version of Waterline"

Comment: `customToJSON: function` don't omit records from database, it will fire when model use JSON.stringify() , look at documentation [link](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson). So when u use res.json(data), res.send() or if u use actions2 exists.success(data) it will fire function `.toJSON()` and this function use `customToJSON` setup. Do u see omitted fields in response?

Comment: I see what's happening - `customToJSON` doesn't run when you search for a record, only when you return it as part of success. However, since my success responseType is 'view', it does not stringify the response so it doesn't omit the fields. When responseType is a different type or when I manually JSON.stringify before returning, it omits the fields.